# How to Change Image Attributes in WordPress Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, image, src, wordpress-hook

Wordpress post showing the following result for image.

```
<img class="large alignnone size-full wp-image-8" src="http://localhost/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/t-radio-city-music-hall.jpg" alt="" width="960" height="654" srcset="http://localhost/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/t-radio-city-music-hall.jpg 960w, http://localhost/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/t-radio-city-music-hall-300x204.jpg 300w, http://localhost/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/t-radio-city-music-hall-768x523.jpg 768w" sizes="(max-width: 960px) 100vw, 960px">
```

How can I change these output as following?

- Remove srcset
- Replace src to data-original

Final result should have attributes: data-original, classes, width, height.

Need WordPress Query.

No jQuery please.

Answer (score 1):

> WordPress has an inbuilt hook to modify or alter image HTML
>   [`wp_get_attachment_image_attributes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_get_attachment_image_attributes/).

Here is the code:

```
function wh_alter_attachment_image($attr)
{
    if (isset($attr['srcset']))
        unset($attr['srcset']);
    if (isset($attr['src']))
    {
        $attr['data-original'] = $attr['src'];
        unset($attr['src']);
    }
    return $attr;
}

add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'wh_alter_attachment_image');
```

*Code goes in [`functions.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**Code is tested and works.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm trying to run code but it doesn't change anything at all. I'm using WP latest version 4.7.4

Comment: I tested in latest version only, then you need to debug, `print_r($attr)` and see what are you getting.

Comment: When I click on image and it's go to standalone page your code working here, but not working on a page where I attached many images.

Comment: This filter could not be used for all images in a post, they're all considered attachments in the db (post type - attachment), but it's actually reserved for the Featured Image/Post Thumbnail.

Comment: It should also be noted that this function no longer runs on the front-end with the block editor. https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/13661